# Unit testing with NUnit. Null object error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nunit, moq

I keep getting a null object reference error when im running one of my unit test.

Unit Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void EnumeratedData_ValidInputType_NoErrorAdded()
    {
        List<String> errorMessageList = new List<string>();
        UserInputEntity myEntity = new UserInputEntity();

        myEntity.DataTypes = new List<string>();
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("DateTime");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("datetime");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("decimal");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("decIMAL");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("DOUble");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("double");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("FLOat");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("float");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("INT");
        myEntity.DataTypes.Add("int");

        PathReader reader = new PathReader();
        IOManager manager = new IOManager(reader);
        VerificationManager testObject = new VerificationManager(manager);

        testObject.EnumeratedDataTypes(myEntity, errorMessageList);
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 0);
    }
```

Method Code:

```
    public void EnumeratedDataTypes(UserInputEntity inputs, List<String> errorMessageList)
    {
        inputs.EnumeratedDataTypes = new int[inputs.DataTypes.Count];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.DataTypes.Count; i++)
            {
                inputs.EnumeratedDataTypes[i] = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.ColumnDataTypes), inputs.DataTypes[i].ToUpper());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessageList.Add(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Enum:

```
class Enumerations
{
    public enum ColumnDataTypes
    {
        DATETIME = 0,
        DECIMAL = 1,
        DOUBLE = 2,
        FLOAT = 3,
        INT = 4
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage:

> FrazerMann.CsvImporter.Entity.Test.EntityVerificationTests.EnumeratedData_ValidInputType_NoErrorAdded:
>   System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Im assumin im overlooking something stupidly simple but i cant see it. id appreciate it if someone could put me out of my misery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `EnumeratedDataTypes` method, you first set the length of the `inputs.EnumeratedDataTypes` property to `inputs.ColumnNames.Count`, which is equal to `0` since it has not been filled with data yet (it is only the `List` *capacity* that has been set to `9`).

Next, when filling this array property with data you loop from `0` to index (including) `inputs.DataTypes.Count`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= inputs.DataTypes.Count; i++)
```

I count the size of the `input.DataTypes` list to `10`. Thus, you will try to write data to an empty array.

I propose the following changes:

***First***, initialize the `inputs.EnumeratedDataTypes` array as follows:

```
inputs.EnumeratedDataTypes = new int[inputs.DataTypes.Count];
```

***Second***, use `<` instead of `<=` in the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.DataTypes.Count; i++)
```

Comment: @Andres you beat me to the answer. Just one clarification, the count is actually 0 as the list has not been used yet.

Comment: @JTMon You are right, sorry! It is of course the `List` _capacity_ that is being set in the constructor, not the predefined _size_. Will update my response accordingly.

Comment: Anders, cheers for replying. Good point about the <= and initializing. Unfortunately its still saying i have an error of the same type. Ill edit my original question with he updated code. +1 though :)

Comment: Do you have more information as to exactly where the exception is thrown? It is not obvious that any part of your code should throw `NullReferenceException`. Could it be that any of the constructors you are calling throws? I am thinking of the `reader`, `manager` and `testObject` initializers.

Comment: Weird, i just reverted back to a previous version, made those changes u suggested and then re-ran the tests and it works. Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it!